# Displaying string based on array variable in a Smarty template

Tags: php, smarty

Hi all want to display the role of user hers is my code

```
if (isset($_SESSION['loggeduser_id']) && $_SESSION['loggeduser_id'] > 0)  {
$loggeduser_id = $_SESSION['loggeduser_id'];
}
if ($loggeduser_id > 0) {

$user = new user();
$role = $user->getrole($loggeduser_id);
$smarty->assign("role",$role);
}
```

And when i type `var_dump($role);`

it show me that

```
array(2) {
[0]=&gt;
string(3) "vip"
["role"]=&gt;
string(3) "vip"
}
```

so i want to show a class in the profile of user in tpl page if is vip user i try to do that and it not working

```
{if $role eq vip}<span class="user-vip-icon"></span>{/if}
```

Can u help me please

Comment: if you see your $role contains an array, using $role[0] or $role[1] would do the job for you!

Comment: so how can be the code

Comment: `{if $role['role'] eq vip}` instead of `{if $role eq vip}`

Comment: `{if $role['role'] == 'vip'}<span class="user-vip-icon"></span>{/if}`

Comment: that too give a blank page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for help me 
i have find solution 
i just make that

`$smarty->assign("role",$role["role"]);` instead of `$smarty->assign("role",$role);`

and i put that in the template `{if $role eq 'vip'}<span class="user-vip-icon"></span>{/if}`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have $role as an array and $role contains array("vip", "vip");
So this should work

```
$role = array("vip", "vip"); // Your ROle
if (in_array("vip", $role)) {
    echo '<span class="user-vip-icon"></span>';
}
```

or

```
if ($role['role'] == "vip") {
    echo '<span class="user-vip-icon"></span>';
}
```

or Smarty Template Code

```
{if $role['role'] == 'vip'}<span class="user-vip-icon"></span>{/if}
```

Comment: It wouldn't give you a blank page, you need to logout the source, since these are html tags, they will be visible view inspect element or view source do check again

Comment: Note that the question is about writing [Smarty](http://smarty.net) templates, not echoing in PHP directly.